# Check if cart is NOT empty in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-wordpress

I can' figure this out, how to check if cart is empty. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirecionar' );
function redirecionar(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( is_page('carrinho-de-compras') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

OR

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
    function vazio() {
        if ( ! WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) { 
           // do something
        }
}
```

---

#### Solved

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
    function vazio() {
        if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { ?>
        <div style="width: 20%;" class="footer-section <?php echo esc_html($woo);?>">
            <a href="<?php echo 'https://my_web_page.pt/finalizar-compra';?>" title="Finalizar Compra"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></a>
        </div>
    <?php   }
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
  function vazio() {
     if (sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) { 
       // do something
     }
   }
```

This will check to see if there are items in the cart.  You can add an else statement or check for equivalence as needed.

Comment: This will not work if using page cache. (cart content will be updated in fragment via ajax)

Answer (score 1):

In new woocommerce 2.1+ : WC()->cart->cart_contents_count to check cart content count

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'redirection_function');
function redirection_function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    }
}
```

To check the cart content you can also use this code:

```
global $woocommerce;
if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count != 0 ) {
    // cart has content
} else {
   // cart is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ajax add to cart you will also want to add this to your JS file:

```
$('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
    if( ! $(this).hasClass('has_items') ) {
        // do something
    }
});
```